# Does Flying Saucer accept HTML not XHTML

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer

My original source is HTML not well formed XHTML. At worse i will have to clean and convert the html to xhtml and then feed flying saucer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flying Saucer does not support HTML; as noted on its [website](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/): "No support for legacy HTML (although there are several open source Java HTML cleaners of varying quality available)." You might try one of the HTML cleaners they suggest, though. One of the best is, not surprisingly, [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The Flying Saucer UserGuide answers my question.

> Flying Saucer is an XML/CSS renderer,
>   which means it takes XML files as
>   input, applies formatting and styling
>   using CSS, and generates a rendered
>   representation of that XML as output.
>   The output may go to the screen (in a
>   GUI), to an image, or to a PDF file.
>   Because we believe most people will be
>   interested in re-using their knowledge
>   of web layout, our main target for
>   content is XHTML 1.0 (strict), an XML
>   document format that standardizes
>   HTML. However, we accept any
>   well-formed XML for rendering as long
>   as CSS is provided that tells us how
>   to lay it out. In the case of XHTML,
>   default stylesheets are provided out
>   of the box and packaged within the
>   library, which means Flying Saucer can
>   render most XHTML out of the box with
>   decent results.

Comment: can u provide some reference to this?